# Submitting via jquery-ajax a form generated among an uncertained number of other forms via php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I generate several forms through a `php` loop like this:

```
for($i=0 ; $i<count($recibidos) ; $i++){  
    $remitente = consultav2("SELECT * FROM mensajes JOIN ".$recibidos[$i]['u_remitente']." ON mensajes.remitente = ".$recibidos[$i]['u_remitente'].".id_".$recibidos[$i]['u_remitente']."
                                                    WHERE mensajes.id_mensaje = '".$recibidos[$i]['id_mensaje']."';");
    echo"
        <tr>
            <form id='recibido".$i."'>
            <td>".$remitente[0]['nombre']." ".$remitente[0]['apellidos']."</td><td>".$remitente[0]['asunto']."</td>
            <td>".$remitente[0]['fecha_mensaje']."</td><td><input type='submit' value='Leer' /></td>
            <input type='hidden' name='accion' value='leer' />
            <input type='hidden' name='id_mensaje' value='".$remitente[0]['id_mensaje']."' />
            </form>
        </tr>
    ";

}
```

The resulting `form` amount is uncertain. The problem is that I want any `form` to get submitted via `jquery-ajax` when clicking on the corresponding `submit` button but I'm having problems in the `jquery` part. My not working proposal is like this...

```
$('[id=^recibido]').each(function(index, value){
  $(this).submit(function(){

    var datos = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'private/control_correo.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: datos,
        success: function(respuesta){
            $('#mostrar_mensaje').html(respuesta).show();
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#mostrar_mensaje').html('Error al intentar leer el mensaje').show();
        }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Can anyone see any problem in my `jquery` code? I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: how is it not working? there are a lot of ways to optimize this (using `.each()`? shame!) but tell us why its not working.

Comment: the target page 'private/control_correo.php' do nothing at all and the div id='mostrar_mensaje' doesn't receive anything from there.

Comment: the target page does nothing ... like it does not process the data you want? have you checked that the variable datos contains items before submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just want to try optimizing it a bit. First, give your php-generated items a class:

```
<form id='recibido".$i."' class="recibidoForm">
```

Then, get rid of the unnecessary `.each` and just use `.on()`

```
$('.recibidoForm').on('submit',function(e){
    var datos = $(this).serialize(),
        $mostrar_mensaje = $('#mostrar_mensaje');

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'private/control_correo.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: datos,
        success: function(respuesta){
            $mostrar_mensaje.html(respuesta).show();
        },
        error: function(){
            $mostrar_mensaje.html('Error al intentar leer el mensaje').show();
        }
    });
});
```

This should do what you want, and be far less overhead. Also, using a class selector like this is far more efficient that using an attribute selector.

Answer (score 1):

your attribute selector is incorrect...`=^`

```
$('[id=^recibido]').each(function(index, value){
//-----^^--here
```

it should be `^=` `jQuery( "[attribute^='value']" )`

```
$('[id^="recibido"]').each(function(index, value){
```

and you don't need each function here..just

```
$('[id^="recibido"]').submit(function(){
  var datos = $(this).serialize();
    .......
   return false;
});
```

should work

Comment: @ogc-nick document says its... `^=` and not `=^`..:)